# UISlider Default

Tags: ios, default, uislider

In the storyboard editor, it is possible to set a "current" value for a UISlider. Is there any way to get this value to use as a reset value after the value of the slider has changed? If not, I guess I'll create a property to store a default value.

Comment: You already answered the question :-)

Answer (score 0):

1. In the storyboard, add a slider to the ViewController
2. In your header file, create a IBOutlet UISlider *slider;
3. In the storyboard, connect this IBOutlet to your slider
4. Click on the slider, Go to attributes inspector and set the value to your desired value.

To access the slider's value at various points during program execution, use the `value` property to get the current value of the slider.

Here's the documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISlider_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. The question was whether it is possible to access the storyboard value after the value has been changed during app execution.

Comment: Yes, and as I mentioned, you use the value property of the slider to get its current value.

Comment: The question is NOT how to get the current value. The question is how to get the storyboard value. Suppose I have a slider with minimum 0.0 and maximum 1.0 and initial value 0.5. The user uses the app for a while changing the slider value eventually to 0.2. Now how do I read 0.5 from the storyboard again? If I check value, I get 0.2, not 0.5.

Comment: When you initialize the storyboard, read the value and store it in `NSUserDefaults`. When you need to access that value, read from there.